# How to convert a beautifulsoup text to list or an iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy, python-requests

How can I convert `beautifulsoup` text to a `list` or a `dictionary`?

I want to get an iterable list from the information I got from the beautifulsoup scraping. For example, now I scraped a quote website and got text, then I want to put this text quote into a list so that I can iterate through them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.great-quotes.com/quotes/category/Motivational")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
# print(soup.prettify())

for quote in soup.find_all("span", class_="edit_body"):
    quotes = list(quotes)  # This gets me an error, name quote not defind
    print(quotes)

# This is is how I want my scraped quotes to look like

new_quote = ['quote', 'quote', 'quote']  # I want it to be in a list.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find_all()` already returns an iterator with all the HTML tags that match your specification. For this reason, you can use the output of this function like a list:

```
quote_list = [quote_tag.text for quote_tag in soup.find_all("span", class_="edit_body")]
print(quote_list)
# Output: ['"What lies behind us and what lies before us are tiny matters compared to what lies within us."', '"Life is like a mirror. Smile at it and it smiles back at you."', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
quotes = [quote for quote in soup.find_all('span', class_='edit_body')]
print(quotes)
```

Comment: It was returning Bolean value , which is not what I want .

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @DrunkCodes i checked this code and it don't return boolean value, it return list of `quotes`

Comment: ok @zimdero nice, I already seen a way around it. Thanks for your care.

Comment: @zimdero do you know how to use web api through a proxy?